# Is a file with 'xml' extension required to parse XML on a BlackBerry?

Tags: java, xml, blackberry

In my application I get a response from a web service which is in xml format.  I am storing that response in a string and then would like to parse the string.  Is it possible to do this or do I need to save the xml data into a file with 'xml' extension?

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your string into an `InputStream`, and parse from there.